# Already logged in when trying to use AD authentication ASP.Net and logoff never works

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, iis-7, active-directory, login-control

I am using AD authentication using forms.  The problem I am facing is that since I have already logged into the network on the computer, the webpage shows that I am already logged in.  And stay logged in even if I click the logoff button.

This happens only when I deploy the website in IIS 7.  When I test the code in debug mode the login/logoff button seems to work fine.

Is there something that needs to change in IIS 7 setting or just the code is incorrect?

Any help is appreciated.

Here is the web.config section of the AD

```
<connectionStrings>
 <add name="ADService" connectionString="LDAP://Dcxxx.xxxx.local"/>
</connectionStrings>

<membership defaultProvider="AspNetActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="AspNetActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider,  System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" attributeMapUsername="sAMAccountName" connectionStringName="ADService" enableSearchMethods="true"/>
      </providers>
```

Then the forms authentication par is

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login.aspx" name=".ADAuthCookie" timeout="15" slidingExpiration="false" protection="All"/>
    </authentication>
    <authorization>
      <deny users="?" />
      <allow users="*" />
    </authorization>
```

In the sitemaster.aspx.cs
I have added the following code to force logging off

```
protected void Unnamed2_LoggingOut(object sender, LoginCancelEventArgs e)
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Session.Clear();
            HttpContext.Current.Session.Abandon();
            ViewState.Clear();
            FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
            Response.Redirect("~/Account/Login.aspx"); 

        }
```

Comment: you don't log off from a Windows auth or AD auth application. That's part of the point. Windows is authenticating the user. Why would you need to log off any way?

Comment: I would not want anyone else to walk to a machine which is not logged off and use the existing authentication to enter data.  Hence I do not want it to automatically log in.

Comment: erm.. that's not an application problem. That's a group policy/security policy problem. If the machine is logged in the person you're worried about walking up to it and entering data, already has more access then they should

Comment: Ok but what about the logoff button ? why is that not working?

Comment: `FormsAuthentication.SignOut();` <-- you're not using forms auth there is **no** sign out to Windows or AD Auth